# Hyphen between words

Tags: writing, style

Does AP Style recommend a hyphen between the words philosophically-inclined?
I have searched several editing and grammar sites and still do not know the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Don't hyphenate.](https://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/hyphens.asp)

"Philosophically" is an adverb, and we don't normally hyphenate "adverb+adjective". At any rate, the hyphen doesn't remove ambiguity, so "if in doubt, leave it out".

I don't think AP has a specific rule on this.

Comment: What is the full form of AP in this context? I googled it and got several full forms for the same. Confused!

Comment: Associated Press. They publish a respected stylebook https://www.apstylebook.com/

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification!